# How to add image multiple times in a layout?

Tags: android, image, android-layout

I am new to this site. I am developing an application on Basic maths for Children .

In that app first i am showing simple calculator . Now I want to insert an image according to 
the 1st of times, in next row image according to 2nd number . So like that I want to show as image wise also Basic Mathematics .

I am not getting how to do that can any one know how to do that or else give me some links to study

Comment: First you study http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html this is use to add the image at calendar formate http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html and also you divide the calendar each cell.

Comment: Is any one is having source code for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent asking questions repetively, 
given the solution here :)

[How to show same image multiple time in row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891578/how-to-show-same-image-multiple-time-in-row)

Answer (score 2):

Please see the following links

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/overview.html

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials.html